# _CrtSetBreakAlloc to track memory leak in a COM object

Tags: c++, visual-c++, com, memory-leaks

When my application finishes, debug build in visual studio prints out all unallocated object and the sequence number of the allocation which was not freed.  Then normally I just put in a call to _CrtSetBreakAlloc(x) where 'x' is the alloc seq number and get a convenient ASSERT at the moment of allocation.  However this doesn't work when the leak happens in a COM object, apparently.  Is there a simple way to use the allocation sequence number to get the execution to stop there?
I tried setting a conditional breakpoint in dbgheap.c and it doesn't trigger either, which I don't understand -- COM object is build as debug.

Answer (score 2):

The function `_CrtSetBreakAlloc` will only work with the C runtime library your module links to. In this case, it will work with the C runtime library linked to your application. I'm assuming your COM object lives in another module (DLL presumably). If the COM object is statically linked to the C runtime library, then calls to `_CrtSetBreakAlloc` will have no effect over the module boundaries, because your app and COM module does not share the same runtime and heap.

Can you modify the source/build of the COM module?

Comment: I can; and I stuck the same call into some constructor inside the COM DLL and it didn't help.  I think the constructor is one o the first allocations that would happen there.  I agree with what you are saying, but it doesn't explain to me why manual breakpoint didn't trigger.